# The SELECT has more than one WHERE clause.

Tags: sql, teradata

Help! I can't figure out why I'm getting this error message: The SELECT has more than one WHERE clause.

The error has to be in the sfd table and within the select statements I'm Unioning because the query worked before I made some changes.

```
SELECT snapshot_date,
inv.sku  ||  inv.warehouse_id,
inv.permalink,
inv.fulfillment_method,
CASE
  WHEN inv.warehouse_id = 'ads' THEN 'ADS (SC)'
  WHEN inv.warehouse_id = 'inoh' THEN 'Innotrac (OH)'
  WHEN inv.warehouse_id = 'innv' THEN 'Innotrac (NV)'
  WHEN inv.warehouse_id = 'inil' THEN 'Innotrac (IL)'
  WHEN inv.warehouse_id = 'kfc' THEN 'Groupon (KFC)'
  WHEN inv.warehouse_id = 'GNNV' THEN 'Genco'
  WHEN inv.warehouse_id = 'GNCA' THEN 'Genco Canada (ON)'
  END AS fp,
CASE WHEN inv.Fulfillable_less_open_orders < 0 THEN 0 ELSE inv.Fulfillable_less_open_orders END AS Fulfillable_less_open_orders2,
inv.Unit_Cost * Fulfillable_less_open_orders2 AS fulfillable_less_open_cogs,
CASE WHEN inv.permalink IS NULL THEN pm.permalink  ||  inv.warehouse_id
  ELSE inv.permalink  ||  inv.warehouse_id
  END AS permalink_grouping,
sfd.opp_id_18,
sfd.md_id_18,
sfd.unit_sell_price,
CASE
     WHEN sfd.feature_date > CURRENT_DATE THEN 's'
  WHEN sfd.feature_date = CURRENT_DATE THEN 'y'
   WHEN live.live_deal IS NOT NULL THEN 'y'
  ELSE 'n'
  END AS deal_status,
CASE
  WHEN cp.id = 193 THEN 'y' ELSE 'n'
  END AS is_clearance2,
sfd.feature_date,
sfd.deal_end_date,
CASE
  WHEN mer.opp_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'TRUE'
  ELSE 'FALSE'
  END AS sku_conflict,
mer.opp_id AS sku_conflict_opp_id,
sfd.option_status

FROM sandbox.inv_snapshot inv
LEFT JOIN ( 
 SELECT * FROM (
 SELECT sfmulti.product_sku AS sku, 
 sfmulti.deal_option_key,
 sfopp.feature_date,
 CASE WHEN sfopp.groupon_expiration_date IS NOT NULL THEN  sfopp.groupon_expiration_date
   ELSE sfopp.feature_end_date
   END AS deal_end_date,
 sfmulti.opportunity_key,
 sfmulti.opportunity_id AS opp_id_18,
 sfmulti.multi_deal_id AS md_id_18,
 sfopp.permalink,
 sfopp.fulfillment_method,
 sfopp.fulfillment_provider,
 sfopp.opportunity_id,
 sfmulti.unit_sell_price,
 sfopp.Grpn_Basics_Flg,
 dopt.status AS option_status
 FROM dw.v_dim_multi_deal sfmulti
 LEFT JOIN dw.v_dim_deal_option dopt ON sfmulti.deal_option_key = dopt.deal_option_key
 LEFT JOIN dw.v_dim_opportunity sfopp ON sfmulti.opportunity_key = sfopp.opportunity_key
 WHERE sfopp.feature_date >= CURRENT_DATE 
  AND sfopp.record_type_key = '751005' -- Selects only Goods deals
  AND sfmulti.product_sku IS NOT NULL
  AND sfopp.fulfillment_method  IN ( 'Owned Inventory','Post-deal purchase 3PL','Pre-deal purchase 3PL')
UNION
 SELECT sfmulti.product_sku AS sku, 
 sfmulti.deal_option_key,
 sfopp.feature_date,
 CASE WHEN sfopp.groupon_expiration_date IS NOT NULL THEN  sfopp.groupon_expiration_date
   ELSE sfopp.feature_end_date
   END AS deal_end_date,
 sfmulti.opportunity_key,
 sfmulti.opportunity_id AS opp_id_18,
 sfmulti.multi_deal_id AS md_id_18,
 sfopp.permalink,
 sfopp.fulfillment_method,
 sfopp.fulfillment_provider,
 sfopp.opportunity_id,
 sfmulti.unit_sell_price,
 sfopp.Grpn_Basics_Flg,
 dopt.status AS option_status
 FROM dw.v_dim_multi_deal sfmulti
 LEFT JOIN dw.v_dim_deal_option dopt ON sfmulti.deal_option_key = dopt.deal_option_key
 LEFT JOIN dw.v_dim_opportunity sfopp ON sfmulti.opportunity_key = sfopp.opportunity_key
 WHERE  sfopp.record_type_key = '751005'
  AND sfmulti.product_sku IS NOT NULL
  AND sfopp.fulfillment_method  IN ( 'Owned Inventory','Post-deal purchase 3PL','Pre-deal purchase 3PL')
  AND sfmulti.opportunity_key IN (
       SELECT dopp.opportunity_key
       FROM dw.v_agg_deal_status_day daystats
       JOIN dw.v_dim_opportunity dopp ON daystats.opportunity_key = dopp.opportunity_key AND daystats.day_key = CAST(CAST(CURRENT_DATE - 1 AS FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD') AS VARCHAR(8)))
       WHERE dopp.record_type_key = '751005' 
       AND daystats.overall_availability_flag = 1)
UNION
 SELECT sfmulti.product_sku AS sku, 
 sfmulti.deal_option_key,
 sfopp.feature_date,
 CASE WHEN sfopp.groupon_expiration_date IS NOT NULL THEN  sfopp.groupon_expiration_date
   ELSE sfopp.feature_end_date
   END AS deal_end_date,
 sfmulti.opportunity_key,
 sfmulti.opportunity_id AS opp_id_18,
 sfmulti.multi_deal_id AS md_id_18,
 sfopp.permalink,
 sfopp.fulfillment_method,
 sfopp.fulfillment_provider,
 sfopp.opportunity_id,
 sfmulti.unit_sell_price,
 sfopp.Grpn_Basics_Flg,
 dopt.status AS option_status
 FROM dw.v_dim_multi_deal sfmulti
 LEFT JOIN dw.v_dim_deal_option dopt ON sfmulti.deal_option_key = dopt.deal_option_key
 LEFT JOIN dw.v_dim_opportunity sfopp ON sfmulti.opportunity_key = sfopp.opportunity_key
 WHERE sfopp.feature_date < CURRENT_DATE 
   AND sfopp.record_type_key = '751005' -- Selects only Goods deals
   AND sfopp.fulfillment_method  IN ( 'Owned Inventory','Post-deal purchase 3PL','Pre-deal purchase 3PL')
   AND  sfmulti.product_sku  || sfopp.fulfillment_provider NOT IN (
     SELECT sfmulti.product_sku  || sfopp.fulfillment_provider
     FROM dw.v_dim_opportunity sfopp
     LEFT JOIN dw.v_dim_multi_deal sfmulti ON sfopp.opportunity_key = sfmulti.opportunity_key  
     JOIN dw.v_agg_deal_status_day daystats ON sfopp.opportunity_key = daystats.opportunity_key AND daystats.day_key = CAST(CAST(CURRENT_DATE - 1 AS FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD') AS VARCHAR(8)))
     WHERE daystats.overall_availability_flag = 1 
     AND sfopp.record_type_key = '751005' 
     AND sfopp.fulfillment_method  IN ( 'Owned Inventory','Post-deal purchase 3PL','Pre-deal purchase 3PL')))
                        QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sfmulti.product_sku, sfopp.fulfillment_provider
                        ORDER BY sfopp.feature_date DESC,
                            sfmulti.opportunity_key DESC,
                            sfmulti.deal_option_key DESC) IN (1)
) AS sfd ON (inv.sku = sfd.sku AND inv.warehouse_id = 
 CASE
     WHEN sfd.fulfillment_provider = 'ADS (SC)' THEN 'ads'
     WHEN sfd.fulfillment_provider = 'Innotrac (OH)' THEN 'inoh'
     WHEN sfd.fulfillment_provider = 'Innotrac (NV)' THEN 'innv'
     WHEN sfd.fulfillment_provider = 'Innotrac (IL)' THEN 'inil'
     WHEN sfd.fulfillment_provider = 'Groupon (KFC)' THEN 'kfc'
     WHEN sfd.fulfillment_provider = 'Genco' THEN 'GNNV'
     WHEN sfd.fulfillment_provider = 'Genco Canada (ON)' THEN 'GNCA'
     END)

 LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT UNIQUE
     sfmulti.product_sku AS sku,
      sfopp.permalink,                
     FROM dw.v_dim_multi_deal sfmulti
     LEFT JOIN dw.v_dim_opportunity sfopp ON sfmulti.opportunity_key = sfopp.opportunity_key
                        QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sfmulti.product_sku 
                        ORDER BY sfopp.feature_date DESC,
                        sfopp.created_date DESC) IN (1)
    WHERE  sfopp.record_type_key = '751005'       
    AND (sfopp.feature_date > (2008-07-01) OR  sfopp.created_date > (2008-07-01))
    AND sfmulti.product_sku IS NOT NULL
    AND sfopp.permalink IS NOT NULL
    AND  sfmulti.product_sku IN (
           SELECT inv2.sku FROM sandbox.inv_snapshot inv2 WHERE permalink IS NULL)
  ) AS pm
    ON inv.sku = pm.sku

LEFT JOIN ( 
SELECT dopp.fulfillment_provider,
dopp.feature_date,
CASE
  WHEN dopp.groupon_expiration_date IS NOT NULL THEN dopp.groupon_expiration_date
  ELSE dopp.feature_end_date 
  END AS deal_end_date,
CASE
  WHEN dopp.feature_date > CURRENT_DATE THEN 'Upcoming'
  WHEN dopp.feature_date <= CURRENT_DATE THEN 'Live'
  ELSE 'Not Live'
  END AS deal_status,
dopp.permalink,
dmulti.opportunity_id AS opp_id,
dmulti.product_sku AS sku
FROM dw.v_dim_opportunity dopp
LEFT JOIN dw.v_dim_deal ddeal
ON dopp.opportunity_key = ddeal.opportunity_key
LEFT JOIN dw.v_dim_multi_deal dmulti
ON dopp.opportunity_key = dmulti.opportunity_key
LEFT JOIN dw.v_dim_deal_option dopt
ON dmulti.deal_option_key = dopt.deal_option_key
                        QUALIFY RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY dmulti.product_sku
                        ORDER BY dopp.feature_date DESC,
                            dmulti.opportunity_key DESC,
                            dmulti.deal_option_key DESC) IN (1)
WHERE dopp.record_type_key = '751005' -- Selects only Goods deals
AND dopp.fulfillment_method LIKE ANY ('%Owned Inventory%','%3PL%')
AND dopp.permalink NOT LIKE ALL ('%rosetta%')
AND  dopt.max_pledges > pledge_sum
AND dopt.status <> 'inactive' -- Not inactive in DE
AND  (dopp.feature_date >= CURRENT_DATE
  OR dopp.opportunity_key IN (
    SELECT dopp.opportunity_key
    FROM dw.v_agg_deal_status_day daystats
    JOIN dw.v_dim_opportunity dopp ON daystats.opportunity_key = dopp.opportunity_key AND daystats.day_key = CAST(CAST(CURRENT_DATE - 1 AS FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD') AS VARCHAR(8)))
    WHERE dopp.record_type_key = '751005' 
    AND daystats.overall_availability_flag = 1))
) AS mer
ON inv.sku = mer.sku AND 
CASE
  WHEN inv.warehouse_id = 'ads' THEN 'ADS (SC)'
  WHEN inv.warehouse_id = 'inil' THEN 'Innotrac (IL)'
  WHEN inv.warehouse_id = 'inoh' THEN 'Innotrac (OH)'
  WHEN inv.warehouse_id = 'innv' THEN 'Innotrac (NV)'
  WHEN inv.warehouse_id = 'kfc' THEN 'Groupon (KFC)'
  WHEN inv.warehouse_id = 'GNNV' THEN 'Genco'
  WHEN inv.warehouse_id = 'GNCA' THEN 'Genco Canada (ON)'
  END <> mer.fulfillment_provider
LEFT JOIN ( 
   SELECT dopp.opportunity_key AS live_deal
   FROM dw.v_agg_deal_status_day daystats
   JOIN dw.v_dim_opportunity dopp ON daystats.opportunity_key = dopp.opportunity_key AND daystats.day_key = CAST(CAST(CURRENT_DATE - 1 AS FORMAT 'YYYYMMDD') AS VARCHAR(8)))
   WHERE dopp.record_type_key = '751005' -- Selects only Goods deals
    AND daystats.overall_availability_flag = '1' -- Determines whether deal is active 
) AS live ON sfd.opportunity_key = live.live_deal
LEFT JOIN user_gp.campaigns c ON sfd.opportunity_id = c.opportunity_id (CASESPECIFIC)
LEFT JOIN user_gp.campaign_personas cp ON c.id = cp.campaign_id AND cp.id = 193
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to narrow this down yourself first. There are multiple UNION's so start by running the queries which get the datasets you are UNIONing individually. that way it wont look like such a mommoth task. once you find the one with multiple WHERE clauses start splitting out individual queries. My guess is that you are missing opening or closing parenthesis somewhere.

Also without even looking too hard, there are easy ways to simplify this down somewhat... I would recommend doing that.